# update PHP version at windows server 2008 having IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, php-manager

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to update PHp version on windows server 2008 R2 having IIS. I checked the version by using command Line : **PHP -v** and it shows **5.4**.And using PHP manager in IIS I changed the version to **5.6** and checked the site is working fine.
But after updating the verison from PHP manager I checked in the command line (php -v) it still shows me PHP 5.4

My question is,what is the difference between the PHP version that is being displayed in the command line and in the PHP manager.

-If they are same then why it did not update the version at server level.

-If they are not the same then how can we make the PHP manager version and server level version same.

-Is it really necessary to update the version at server level as well or we can carry on by updating the version just at PHP manager.

PHP version after changing from PHP manager:

[image]

PHP version showing in the command line even after updating in IIS using PHp manager:

[Updating the PHP path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgLv3.png)

Comment: Check that your PATH in your environment variables points to the new version and not the old. When that's done, restart the CMD window and try again. If it still doesn't work, restart the computer and try again.

Comment: You should remove the "wordpress"-tag since the question has _nothing_ to do with wordpress. Alos, remove the whole paragraph that starts with "Please reply to me..." since won't help you to get answers. It rather sounds a bit like: _"Just do as I say and answer!"_, which isn't a nice way of asking for help.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson removed

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have restarted the server i ll let u know if it updates now. thanks

Comment: You didn't answer the initial question. Did you make sure that the PATH in the servers environment variables points to the correct version? (You must remove the path to the old PHP-version).

Comment: Yes I did. let me add the screenshot

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can u pls check the image. Am i doing it right coz it dint update

Comment: Please read my comments again: _"You must remove the path to the old PHP-version"_, which it doesn't looks like you did.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I removed old version from IIS manager->Machine name->Handler mapping. Removed from control panel(win cache for 5.4).removed the folder from program files. and now I am getting error 'php is not recognized as internal or external command'when I write 'php -v' after setting up new path.

Comment: Now its done. Thank u very much @MagnusEriksson for ur help.

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it.